# Inserting shared pointers to strings from cin into vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, shared-ptr

I am trying to insert shared pointers to strings into a vector using the copy algorithm. Is it possible to read lines from the istream and store shared_ptr's to those strings in a vector using the copy algorithm? So far I'm stuck with the following class.

```
class DVector
{
    typedef vector<shared_ptr<string>> PTSVector;
    PTSVector data;

public:
    void push_back()
    {
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            back_inserter(data));
    }
};
```

Can anyone tell me what might go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want pointers to a std::string in the first place? Do not use any pointer (smart or not smart) without reason!

Comment: The code above was an example. I would like to store share pointers to objects which allocate memory in a vector. With the smart pointers I want to make sure that no memory leaks will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::copy` isn't appropriate here, because you're reading strings, but trying to store pointers to strings.

Your source and destination types are different, so you need `std::transform`, instead. This function is similar to copy, but it applies a function to transform the input before writing it to the output iterator.

```
transform(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(data), 
    [](const string& str) { return make_shared<string>(str); });
```

Comment: Thanks, I should look more at the facilities of STL!